# Last element of two list recursion

Tags: haskell, recursion

This is a part of home exercise, which I've thought through, but don't understand last obstacle.

Idea of task is to implement unusual substring function, which works in following way:

> Write a function `commonSubstring :: String -> String -> String` that, given two strings `s1` and `s2`, computes a common “substring” of `s1` and `s2` as follows. The function finds the earliest common character `c` (closest to *head* of either `s1` or `s2` appearing in both sequences). The function removes `c` and all the characters before it in both strings, puts `c` in the output string, and continues.
>
> If there are two candidates for the earliest common character, pick the one from `s1`.

And example of calling such function would be:

> ```hs
> commonSubstring "XabcdefgY" "abcdefgXY"
> > "XY"
>
> commonSubstring "abcdefgXY" "XabcdefgY"
> > "abcdefgY"
> ```

So, I've implemented following recursion, which kinda works:

```hs
commonSubstring :: String -> String -> String
commonSubstring first_string second_string 
    | length(second_string)==0=[]
    | take 1 first_string ==take 1 second_string=take 1 first_string ++ commonSubstring (tail first_string)(tail second_string)
    | otherwise=commonSubstring first_string (tail second_string)
```

Question is: Why doesnt function return final symbol from matching pairs of heads?

```hs
commonSubstring "abcdefgXY" "XabcdefgY"
>"abcdefg"

commonSubstring "XabcdefgY" "abcdefgXY"
>"X"
```

Comment: You should be using pattern matching instead of lots of `tail` and `take 1` calls.

Comment: could you please show me, how this works? haskell is surprisingly.. hard for me, especially recursions.

Comment: got task accepted, but would love to know alternative, better ways to implement asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a hint:

```hs
commonSubstring :: String -> String -> String
commonSubstring [] _ = ??
commonSubstring (c:cs) s2 =
  case dropWhile ?? s2 of
    [] -> ??
    d:ds -> ??
```

What should the result be if the first string is empty? Suppose the first string has at least one character, `c`. You have two cases to consider: `c` occurs in `s2` or it doesn't. If it doesn't, then you want to skip `c` and move on. If it does, you want to produce `c` and continue with what came after in each string. Can you fill in the `??`s above?

Answer (score 0):

Just figured it out, actually an easy, but still - interesting question.

```hs
   ...
   | length(second_string)==1=take 1 second_string
```

is there a more correct way to return the latest element of recursive list?

Comment: you sure this is right? I think the exercise did ask of you to implement a different algorithm (it is spelled out rather clearly that you should find a common character, remove it from both Strings, output it and continue recursively - you did some kind of move along algorithm - as an example where I think yours fail: try to reverse the input

Comment: I don't think your function matches the given specifications. What you here basically do is scan the two strings. If the characters do not match, you move the scanner of the second string. But this will not always obtain the earliest character. Since it is possible that the first character of the second string appears in the first one.

Comment: well.. this works:
commonSubstring :: String -> String -> String
commonSubstring first_string second_string 

    | length(second_string)==1=take 1 second_string
    | take 1 first_string ==take 1 second_string=take 1 first_string ++ commonSubstring (tail first_string)(tail second_string)
    | otherwise=commonSubstring first_string (tail second_string)